# Is any great support from WWF to MS CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Can we use WWF with MS CRM extensively?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Custom XAML workflows, also called declarative workflows, allow you to harness the power of Windows Workflow Foundation to create reusable workflows for Microsoft Dynamics 365 & deploy in CRM but with some limitations. CRM online is unsupported because of sandbox restrictions.

> The workflows that are created or modified outside of Microsoft Dynamics CRM cannot be viewed or modified in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM process designer. You can only change the status (Activate or Deactivate) of these workflows. These workflows will run in Microsoft Dynamics CRM as per the workflow definition.

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309458.aspx)